# Range is returning a nothing value

Tags: vba

I wrote a code to find date in a column. It worked initially. After I made a few adjustments, it started returning a "nothing" value in the watch window

```
Sub test()
  Dim strDate as string
  Dim rcell as range

StrDate = date

Set rcell= range("A:A").Find(Cdate(strDate))

End sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you trying to find the first cell after cell `A1` **containing** today's date in column `A`  (i.e. you are using only `1(9)` parameter (`What`) of the [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method)? Do the cells have values or formulas? Please do clarity. You can also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63974943/edit) your question using the edit button below your post.

Comment: If it returns `Nothing`, that means it was not found. Keep in mind that a `Date` value is not the same thing as a `String` value that looks like a date.